# Prestashop 1.5, How to copy a core module into my theme module folder?

Tags: module, prestashop-1.5

I'de like to copy the [prestashop new theme]cart block (cartblock2 in the main module folder) into my theme/modules in order to customize it and keep the core module intact.

How do I do that ? I searched the documentation and it's not very clear...

What I did so far :

Copy cartblock2 from the main module folder into my theme/module folder, empty prestashop cache (it's turned off but just to be sure), I made my changes but nothing change it's only changing when I modify the module in the main module folder.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

module folder name must same with root modules name

/modules/blockcart2

in themes

/themes/modules/blockcart2

and you can only edit blockcart2.tpl file in themes folder

and make sure blockcart2 installed in bacoffice